# I can't open Android studio on mac

Tags: android

I open android studio today, And it appear like this picture. i don't know what is the problem? can anyone tell me. thank

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/834h6.jpg)

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: El Captain that is the last version of OS X

Comment: I have heard there were some problems with running Android Studio on El Capitan (which is why I am still on Yosemite), maybe try uninstalling/reinstalling Android Studio and your Java Package? Here are some other answers for the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31502426/5115932

Answer (score 0):

I have the same bug when importing a existing gradle project into AS. Closing the project and reopening it resolves the issue. Hope it will help you

Comment: I have close and try to open the project several time. but it doesn't fix the problem. i also try to restart my mac and reopen AS too but still no luck.